# Copy the formula to the whole list

Tags: excel, vba

I have a piece of code that copies a specific formula from one worksheet to another. I'm having trouble applying this formula to all rows in a particular column. Is there a way to copy the formula downwards? The formula I use is : =IFERROR(IF(SEARCH("100",D2),"YES",""),"") so the next cell(A3) should have this formula =IFERROR(IF(SEARCH("100",D3),"YES",""),"") and so on.

```
Dim x As Variant
Dim y As Variant

x = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sample").Range("A2").formula 

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sample 1").Range("A2").Value = x

Dim numr As Integer
numr = Range("X2").End(xlDown).Row 'calculating all the rows
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to pass `x` around.  This assumes that when you calculate `numr` that you are in the proper sheet.  This will fill the range with the formula.

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sample 1").Range("A2") = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sample").Range("A2")

Dim numr As Long
numr = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sample 1").Cells(Rows.Count, "X").End(xlUp).Row 'calculating all the rows
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sample 1").Range("A2:A" & numr).FillDown
```